# Does linear combination of periodic functions is periodic?

Tags: vector-spaces, periodic-functions

> Does linear combination of periodic functions is periodic?

I know that if $f$ is periodic and $g$ is periodic then $f+g$ is periodic. But what about the linear combination of two periodic functions???

> Whether set of all periodic functions is a Vector Space over any Field.

Comment: Maybe this will help. If $h=f+g$ is periodic, and $g$ is periodic, then by what you said $h+g=f+2g$ is periodic.

Comment: Why should the sum be periodic? If the functions have commensurable periods, then yes.

Comment: What you know, isn't so. $\sin x+\sin\sqrt2x$ isn't periodic.

Answer (score 3):

Linear combination of periodic functions need not to be periodic.

If $f_1, f_2, f_3, \dots, f_k$ are periodic functions with fundamental periods $T_1, T_2, T_3, \dots, T_k$ respectively, then $\sum _{i=1} ^k a_i f_i$ where $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$ are constants is periodic if $\text{lcm } (T_1, T_2, \dots, T_k)$ exists.

Example: $f(x) = \sin x$ with period of $2 \pi$, $g(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ with   period $2$. Then $h(x) = f(x) + g(x) = \sin x + \sin(\pi x)$
 is not periodic since the least common multiple of $2 \pi$ (an irrational number) and $2$ (a rational number) does not exist.